# libgphoto2-2-dev is installed, but pkg-config wont list it. Deb Wheezy new install

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude, debian-wheezy

I am trying to use node-gphoto2 from npm, but I am having trouble with the libgphoto2-2-dev dependency. I've installed it, but pkg-config says it's not there.

```
$ sudo aptitude search gphoto
p   gphoto2                         - The gphoto2 digital camera command-line c
p   gphotofs                        - filesystem to mount digital cameras      
i A libgphoto2-2                    - gphoto2 digital camera library           
i   libgphoto2-2-dev                - gphoto2 digital camera library (developme
p   libgphoto2-dev-doc              - gphoto2 digital camera library (developme
i A libgphoto2-l10n                 - gphoto2 digital camera library - localize
i A libgphoto2-port0                - gphoto2 digital camera port library      
v   libgphoto2port                  -
```

So yes, libgphoto2-2-dev is reported as installed, but:

```
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep photo
libgphoto2_port                libgphoto2_port - Device-independent access to serial, USB, and other ports
libgphoto2                     libgphoto2 - Library for easy access to digital cameras
```

pkg-config says it's not. What do I need to do to diagnose this problem? I've looked at the related questions, and $PKG_CONFIG_PATH is blank.

**Edit**: Here's the line in the build which is failing:

```
(pkg-config libgphoto2 || dpkg -s libgphoto2-2-dev || (echo 'ERROR: libgphoto2 seems not to be installed.' 1>&2; exit 1)) && node-gyp rebuild
```

Comment: Could you post the output of the `pkg-config` that tells you it is not installed?

Comment: To me, the `pkg-config` output seems to indicate that libgphoto2 _is_ present.

Comment: I think `pkg-config` should list `libgphoto2-2-dev`.

Comment: That’s just the Debian package name. `pkg-config libgphoto2` should work; what happens when you try `pkg-config --libs libgphoto2`?